# Creating node forms

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

Does anyone know how to create a node form for specific Content Types? Instead of clicking *Content > Add Content > Content Type* they can just, I don't know, go to the sidebar and fill out the info there.

This would be great for Content Types which allow Anonymous access like a *Testimonials* Content Type. There's a short something over at http://goo.gl/LMpSS but it doesn't really explain anything and leaves you wanting for more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [Form Block](http://drupal.org/project/formblock) module.
This module simply exposes node forms in blocks. You'll get an extra set of options for each content type, which enables/disables the block.

If you need to do it programmatically, `node_add()` is the best way to go, as suggested by @kiamlaluno.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the code for [node_add()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.pages.inc/function/node_add/7) as a guideline.

```
function mymodule_node_form($type) {
  global $user;

  $output = array();
  $types = node_type_get_types();

  if (isset($types[$type])) {
    $node = (object) array(
      'uid' => $user->uid,
      'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
      'type' => $type,
      'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
    );

    $output = drupal_get_form($type . '_node_form', $node);
  }

  return $output;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, you can also use node_add() directly see my answer below.

Comment: I had to add the line module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages'); in order to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Shamelessly lifted from SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344754/drupal-7-how-to-display-node-add-sometype-form-on-another-page#answer-7740337

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$form = node_add('node_type');
```

Kudos to @"Marius Ilie"

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try, but I think that you have to create a display (block, content panel, view, etc) and put the `drupal_get_form()` call in this display.

You can create a display programmatically (`hook_block_view()` for example), or you can use the Views module. With this module you create a new view (at admin/structure/views), add a display ('block' for example), then you add 'a global text area' (in header or footer)  where you past his PHP Code (don't forget to change the formater of the global text, 'Filtered HTML' to 'PHP Code'.

To finish, if you created a block, you can place it where you want (with the admin UI at admin/structure/block).